# Wikidata SPARQL - get company entities and the location of their headquarters

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm having trouble extracting location attributes of company HQ's.

My [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Sample%20to%20query%20all%20values%20of%20a%20property%0A%23%20Property%20talk%20pages%20on%20Wikidata%20include%20basic%20queries%20adapted%20to%20each%20property%0ASELECT%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fweb%20%3Fisin%20%3Fhq%20%3Fhqloc%20%3Finception%0A%0A%23%20valueLabel%20is%20only%20useful%20for%20properties%20with%20item-datatype%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ783794.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Fweb.%7D%20%23%20get%20item%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP946%20%3Fisin.%7D%20%23%20get%20item%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP571%20%3Finception.%7D%20%23%20get%20item%0A%20%20optional%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP159%20%3Fhq.%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20optional%7B%3Fitem%20p%3AP159%20%3FhqItem.%20%23%20get%20property%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FhqItem%20ps%3AP159%20wd%3AQ515.%20%23%20get%20property-statement%20wikidata-entity%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FhqItem%20pq%3AP17%20%3Fhqloc.%20%23%20get%20country%20of%20city%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%2010): finds all companies or sub-classes, and returns some basic properties such as ISIN and URL, and the Headquarter location.

I have tried to use [this example](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/wikidata-get-property-of-property/10640) to extend the Headquarter part of the query to return location information such as city, country, and [coordinate latitude and longitude](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#All_museums_(including_subclass_of_museum)_in_Washington,_D.C._with_coordinates). However I am getting stuck on pulling the values or labels through.

Thank you

```
SELECT
  ?item ?itemLabel ?web ?isin ?hq ?hqloc ?inception

# valueLabel is only useful for properties with item-datatype
WHERE 
{
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q783794.

  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P856 ?web.} # get item
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P946 ?isin.} # get item
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P571 ?inception.} # get item
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P159 ?hq.}  

  OPTIONAL{?item p:P159 ?hqItem. # get property
           ?hqItem ps:P159 wd:Q515. # get property-statement wikidata-entity
           ?hqItem pq:P17 ?hqloc. # get country of city
           }

  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: what exactly does not work with the query? getting the cities works, or not?

Comment: what is the purpose of `?hqItem ps:P159 wd:Q515.` ? if you try to filter for cities, the relation `ps:P159` is clearly wrong. In Wikidata, "instance of" relation is `wdt:P31`

Comment: `SELECT  ?item ?itemLabel ?web ?isin ?hqLabel ?hqloc ?hqCountry ?hqCountryLabel ?inception
WHERE {
  #values ?item {wd:Q74687} # for debugging
  ?item p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q783794.
        
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P856 ?web.} # get website
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P946 ?isin.} # get ISIN
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P571 ?inception.} # get inception date`

Comment: `OPTIONAL{?item p:P159 ?hqStmt. # get HQ statement
           ?hqStmt ps:P159 ?hq. # get HQ item
           ?hqStmt pq:P625 ?hqloc. # get HQ coordinate location qualifier
           optional {?hq wdt:P17 ?hqCountry} # optional, the country of the HQ
           }
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
} LIMIT 10`

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more simplified query to select some of the values you mentioned:

```
SELECT
?company ?companyLabel ?isin ?web ?country ?countryLabel ?inception

WHERE 
{
     ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
     ?article schema:about ?company . 

     ?company p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q783794.

     ?company wdt:P946 ?isin. 
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P856 ?web.}
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P571 ?inception.}
     OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P17 ?country.}

     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
} LIMIT 10
```

What I changed:

- changed some labels to be more explicit (ex: "?item" -> "?company")
- usage of P17 to directly select the country
- I removed the OPTIONAL on ISIN to show that there exist some values. You did not get a result because it seems that many company instances on Wikidata lack that information.

From here, selecting the other values should be easy.